# Wordpress Theme: JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am attempting to design my own `wordpress` theme, but I'm having issues getting my `JavaScript` to work, and nothing I have researched seems to have the answer. If anyone can help me out I'd greatly appreciate it!

Things I have done:

Enqueue my javascript file in functions.php:

```
function sorenTheme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_register_script( 'soren-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/soren-script.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-core' ), '1', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('soren-script');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sorenTheme_scripts');
```

Create a simple javaScript file in the directory {template folder}/js named soren-script.js, which currently just contains a very simple alert test

```
alert('Hello World');
```

and that's it. When I tried to put the alert in the `index.php file` directly using the `script tags`, the alert came up as expected, but when I move it to the js file I get nothing. Is there something i need to add to the `.php` or `.js` files?

EDIT: When I look at the developer console, the source files include jquery, my css file, etc but not soren-script.js

So I guess getting soren-script.js to show up would fix the problem but I don't know how to do that, i thought the enqueue would make it automatically show up as a source, as it did with my style sheet

Comment: What does your browser console output look like?

Comment: The browser console doesn't have anything relating to the alert, just the message "Consider using 'dppx' units instead of 'dpi', as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) "

Comment: do you have the 'wp_footer()' hook in your index.php file?

Comment: yes, at the beginning of my php i have <?php get_header(); ?> and at the end of it I have <?php get_footer(); ?>

Comment: see my answer. get_footer =/= wp_footer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't have the wp_footer() function in your template. Since in this hook the code will get loaded it won't appear if you haven't defined the hook.

> **$in_footer**
>   (boolean) (optional) Normally, scripts are placed in  of the HTML document. If this parameter is true, the script is placed before the  end tag. This requires the theme to have the wp_footer() template tag in the appropriate place.
>   Default: false

ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Note that `get_footer()` and `wp_footer()` are [2 different things](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45299/what-is-the-difference-between-the-wp-footer-and-get-footer-actions):

> The **get_footer()** template tag is a custom wrapper for the locate_template() function, used to include a template-part file within a template file. The get_footer() template tag is part of the WordPress template system, and is used primarily by the Theme itself, to specify the footer.php or footer-{slug}.php file to include in the current template.
>
> The **wp_footer()** template tag is a custom wrapper for the wp_footer action hook, which is invoked via do_action( 'wp_footer' ). The wp_footer() template tag is part of the WordPress Hooks API, and is used primarily by Plugins, to inject scripts in the site HTML footer.

The wp_footer hook is typically placed right befor the closing body tag:

```
<?php
    wp_footer();
?>
</body>
```

cfr.: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer

Comment: so $in_footer is a parameter in my wp_enqueue_script function call, but I set it as false. I thought that that would mean I wouldn't need to worry about wp_footer? Or do I still need it even if it's false?

Comment: In you're example it's set to true. And you should always include wp_footer() since lot's of plugins also use this hook to insert scripts etc. And not including this will break a lot of plugins

Comment: FYI it's the last true in: wp_register_script( 'soren-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/soren-script.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-core' ), '1', true );

Comment: oh woww lol i thought i had set it to false X) all the scripts are loading now! thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to include your script like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script('scriptname', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scriptname.js', array(), '20140520', true);
```

Second thing. Have you put the alert in a document.ready or something?

Comment: I have tried to add my script using the one line enqueue as shown, and no results. Also, no, i didn't use document.ready, just the one line shown in my post. Do i need a document.ready?

Comment: No. you don't need a document.ready. Sometimes it's useful but you dont need it.
Have you got another script with the same name? That's a failure I have done a few times. Then the script wont be loaded.

Comment: Is your script included but not executed or isnt it included at all?

Comment: I just added an edit explaining that. It doesn't seem to be included because I can't find it as a source file in my developer console

Comment: As others have written, check your footer.php if it contains the "wp_footer();"

Answer (score 0):

In your functions.php add the following;

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    wp_enqueue_script(
       'script name', 
       get_template_directory_uri() . '/functions/js/script.js', 
       array('jquery') // any script dependancies. i.e. jquery
    );
});
```

In your file manager, place your script in the functions/js/ folder.

Ensure the following opens and closes your script.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
}
```

This has worked a treat for me and should be all you need to get js working right on a wordpress theme